# Non-singularity of $Df$ implies that $f$ is locally one-to-one

Tags: vector-analysis, intuition

I'm on the following lemma, in the  Inverse Function Theorem section of Munkres's Analysis Book:

> Let $A$ be a open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be of class $\mathscr{C}^{1}$.
> If $Df(a)$ is non-singular, there exists an $\alpha>0$ s.t the inequality $$||f(x)-f(y)||\geq \alpha ||x-y||$$holds for all $x,y$ in some open cube $C(a;\epsilon)$ in some open cube $C(a;\epsilon)$ centered at $a$. It follows that $f$ is one-to-one on this open cube.

I understand the formal component of the proof given in the book (why each step implies the next one). But I couldn't grasp the philosophy (or the intuitive idea) behind it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The intuitive idea is the following: $Df(a)$ is the linear approximation of the (nonlinear) function $f(x)-f(a)$ as a function of $x-a$. From linear algebra, if a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is non-singular, it is one to one (actually a bijection). The idea is that if the linear approximation has that property, the function itself is also locally one-to-one. It is very easy to see it in dimension 1: if $f'(a)\neq 0$, your function is locally increasing or decreasing, which clearly implies locally one-to-one.